# Time series with semi-annual data

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I stumbled across one question during my preparation for the exam, which I do not have any idea on how to approach it.

***The question is the following:***

Consider the real model y(i)=a+b*x(i)+u(i), where u(i)~IN(0,1), i=1,2,....T. The model refers to semi-annual data, however we have the observations in 2 types:

Case 1: Annual data, so then, the observed variable y(1)^ = y(1)+y(2); y(2)^=y(3)+y(4) and so on. The observations for x(i)^, have the same rule as in case of y(i)^. Considering that T is even, so the annual data observed is an integer number=T/2,

Case 2: Moving averages, meaning that y(1)^^=((y(1)+y(2))/2, y(2)^^=((y(2)+y(3))/2, and so on. As before, observations for x(i)^^, follow the same rule.

***Questions:***

a) What are the properties of the errors in both cases (y(i)^,x(i)^) and (y(i)^^,x(i)^^)

b) How would you estimate the beta coefficient in case of annual data, and in the case of moving-averages.

c) From the perspective of estimating beta and alpha coefficients, what would you prefer, annual or moving-average data?

Comment: I think if you could write this in latex it would be easier for everybody.